# npgsql search_path not working

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I've a script like the following:

```
SET search_path = MySchema;
INSERT INTO MyTable() values ()
```

MyTable is actually created in MySchema, so if I change the script to 
    INSERT INTO MySchema.MyTable() values ()
It works
Now I'm generating some SQL files to recreate a database structure, so we have the scripts generated with  "SET search_path = MySchema;"

Is there a way to make this work?

Using NPGSQL version 3.0.4.0

Comment: Apparently the search path can be defined in the connection string: "Search Path  Sets the schema search path." See ["Connection String Parameters"](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html) - "Misc". Maybe this is an option for you?

Comment: Thank you, it helped to sort the issue, but my actual problem was related to having DDL and DML on the same script.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, it's not related to the schema itself, the issue is when having both DDL and DML instructions together.